# How do Java generics types ensure only the right type of object is added?

Tags: java, generics, arraylist

How does a generic class like Arraylist ensure that only the correct type of object is added to it if the type is erased at compile time? I know class cast get added by the compiler but that seems to be for only when retrieving objects from the class. Does the add method have class casts as well?

Comment: The compiler does not allow the program to compile if you try to add the wrong type.

Comment: It doesn’t. The compiler will warn you if you cast the list to a different type, but at run time nothing cares.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's look how to check this.

*Foo.java*

```
public class Foo extends Bar { }
```

*Baz.java*

```
List<Bar> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add(new Foo());
//list.add("boo"); ***ERROR***
```

In the above the compiler ensures that only Bar's are added.

After compilation we change `Foo.java` and compile it separately:

*Foo.java*

```
public class Foo { }
```

When we run with the new Foo.class we may expect a `ClassCastException` on using an element from the list. Adding probably will not throw an exception, as with type erasure only Object is required.